# Which AI conference presentation on predicting terrorist movement inside buildings caused protest in the audience and media?

Tags: ethics

I remember reading an online news article a while ago on AI ethics that described a conference presentation on the subject of a military AI system that predicted terrorist movement inside buildings and used drones to shoot them when they exited the building. The presentation caused protests and sharp criticism in the audience due to the dehumanizing nature of the AI usage presented.

The article was in mainstream media, but I am unable to find it with Google search.

Which AI conference presentation was it and are any articles on it available?